# How can I use a nested while loop in a loop?

Tags: ti-basic

When I run the code below, it works fine. (TI nspire CAS II calculator)
However, at the end of the program I give two options, **"Enter"** to repeat the program, **"Esc"** to quit.

"Esc" works fine.
However if I pick "Enter", the RequestStr box pops up again to receive the new input as intended.
When I enter the input, the program displays **"You entered nothing"** and goes back to the RequestStr box again. I have to press "Cancel" on the RequestStr box to get out of the loop.
**"You entered nothing"** is part of the error code I am using to intercept the case where the user may click OK without entering anything into the box.
So basically the program works fine the first time I run it, it is when I choose to rerun it again is when the issue arises.

**CODE**

```
Define LibPub funvarsolv()=
Prgm
:Local y1,res,i,ab,d,c
:
:Loop
:0→c
:1→d
:While d =1
:Try
:RequestStr "enter function",y1,0,ab
:0→d
:
:Else
:© user left input box empty
:Text "you entered nothing",0
:ClrErr
:
:EndTry
:If d=0
:Exit
:EndWhile

:© user pressed cancel 
:  If ab=0 Then
:      Disp "Press ENTER to  end"
:                subrtine\delay()
:                  DelVar y1,i,k,ab
:                           Return
:
:EndIf
:
:
:
: expr("Define y1(x) ="&y1)
: res:=exp▶list(solve(y1(x)=0,x),x)
:
:Disp "Solution set: "&var&" =",res
:
:subrtine\dlay()
:If k="esc" Then
:1→c
:ElseIf k="enter" Then
:0→c
:EndIf
:If c=1
:Exit
:EndLoop
:EndPrgm
```